# NesJS RabbitMQ with @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq no connection when using new connectioninit

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

Using `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq` I tried the connection manager to not wait for a connection. According to the [readme](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/rabbitmq#connection-management) it can handle reconnections and wait for a connection without crashing the app. However, when I use the `connectionInitOptions` as stated and set `wait` to `false`, I get a connection error. When I don't use it (default behavior setting `wait` to `true`) , it connects to the RabbitMQ server. Below are examples importing the RabbitMQModule in a NestJS module.

This works and connects to the RabbitMQ server

```js
RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
      exchanges: [{ type: 'topic', name: 'main' }],
      uri: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672',
    }
```

This doesn't work and won't connect

```js
RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
      exchanges: [{ type: 'topic', name: 'main' }],
      uri: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672',
      connectionInitOptions: {
        wait: false,
      },
```

With the second option I get the following error:

```
Error: AMQP connection is not available
    at AmqpConnection.publish (/home/xxx/node_modules/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq/src/amqp/connection.ts:424:13)
    at BootstrapService.onApplicationBootstrap (/home/xxx/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.service.ts:20:25)
    at MapIterator.iteratee (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-app-bootstrap.hook.js:22:43)
    at MapIterator.next (/home/xxx/node_modules/iterare/src/map.ts:9:39)
    at IteratorWithOperators.next (/home/xxx/node_modules/iterare/src/iterate.ts:19:28)
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at IteratorWithOperators.toArray (/home/xxx/node_modules/iterare/src/iterate.ts:227:22)
    at callOperator (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-app-bootstrap.hook.js:23:10)
    at callModuleBootstrapHook (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-app-bootstrap.hook.js:43:23)
    at NestApplication.callBootstrapHook (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:199:55)
    at NestApplication.init (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:98:9)
    at NestApplication.listen (/home/xxx/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:33)
    at bootstrap (/home/xxx/src/main.ts:12:3)
```

The last line (main.ts:12:3) is the `app.listen(3000)` statement.
There are other options you can set with the `connectionInitOptions` (`reject` and `timeout`) and I've tried the combinations but still no connection.

RabbitMQ is running in a docker container on Linux but that should be no problem. I posted the same question on NestJS discord but got no reply, so hopefully someone on SO has an idea.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was using the connection in a `onApplicationBootstrap` method and then the connection is apparently not present yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for connection asynchronously 'onApplicationBootstrap':
or on :

```
  async onModuleInit() {
     await this.amqpConnection.managedChannel.waitForConnect(async () => {
     await this.assertQueueAndBindToExchange(
      transferRequestQueueName,
      transferRequestExchangeName,
      createdRoutingKey
    );
```